# Using cursor.next() is resetting "row in cursor" causing it to skip every other row

Tags: arcpy, cursor, arcgis-10.6

I'm trying to update a column based on the value in the next row, but `cursor.next()` is giving unexpected behavior. When I identify the *next_row* using `cursor.next()`, it is resetting my `row in cursor`! The result is my loop goes over every other row, not every row. What am I missing? (Code below is just to show cursor behavior; code for row update for column has been stripped.)

**Code**

```
import arcpy
temp1 = r'mypath\mypointfile.shp'
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(temp1, ['OID@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            row_next = cursor.next()
            print 'current_oid=', row[0], 'next_oid=', row_next[0]
        except StopIteration:
            print 'no rows'
        except:
            print 'something else went wrong'
```

**Actual Prints**

```
current_oid= 0 next_oid= 1
current_oid= 2 next_oid= 3
current_oid= 4 next_oid= 5
current_oid= 6 next_oid= 7
current_oid= 8 next_oid= 9
```

**Expected Prints**

```
current_oid= 0 next_oid= 1
current_oid= 1 next_oid= 2
current_oid= 2 next_oid= 3
current_oid= 3 next_oid= 4
current_oid= 4 next_oid= 5
```

**UPDATE**

Purpose of this is to only keep rows that are the first or last point in the group.

*Example attributes:*

```
oid group   id
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   2   1
4   2   2
5   3   1
6   3   2
7   3   3
8   3   4
9   3   5
```

*Desired attributes:*

```
group   id
1   1
1   3
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   5
```

**Original code, that didn't work because cursor.next() skips rows:**

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(temp1, ['OID@', 'group', 'id']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        group_current = row[1]
        id_current = row[2]
        if id_current == 1:
            check = "keep"
        else:
            try:
                row_next = cursor.next()
                group_next = row_next[1]
                id_next = row_next[2]
                if id_next == 1:
                    check = "keep"
                else:
                    check = "remove"
            except StopIteration:
                check = "keep"
            except:
                print 'something else went wrong'
            if check != "keep":
                cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: `next` isn't needed, because you're in a `for` loop. You can't read ahead, but you can preserve the current in `previous` then act on that later.

Comment: @Vince As stated in question, purpose is to perform UpdateCursor on a specific column based on values in another column. The printing of the oid values was for illustration of skipping behavior. I will be calculating the value in "mycol" in row4 based on the value in "myotherCol" in row5.

Comment: No, you can't read ahead without losing the current row. You need to use cursor as it *actually* operates, not how you wish it did. What you *can* do is save your values in a dictionary with a SearchCursor scan with an OID key, the run an update pass later. I've cached tens of millions of rows with a 32-bit Python and hundreds of millions with 64-bit Python, so 15k rows is a drop in the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected as it's how python generators work, once a value is consumed, it's gone. If your feature class isn't toooo big, pull all the rows into a list, then use enumerate and indexing to access the next row.  E.g.

```python
cursor = ((i,) for i in range(10))  # Fake a cursor as I'm not at a PC with ArcGIS
rows = list(cursor)  # Exhaust the generator
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    try:
        row_next = rows[i+1]
        print(row[0],row_next[0])
    except IndexError:
        print('no rows')
```

Output:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
no rows
```

Or... turn it around, grab the first row before the loop then refer to the previous row instead of the next row:

```python
prev_row = next(cursor)
for row in cursor:
    print(prev_row[0], row[0])
    prev_row = row
```

Output:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
```

Comment: I'm doing this for many files, and my smallest one has about 15k rows. As stated in question, purpose is to perform UpdateCursor on a specific column based on values in another column. The printing of the oid values was for illustration of skipping behavior.

Comment: Either method should work. Use a `SearchCursor` to get the list before using the `UpdateCursor`, a few million values in a list isn't going to be an issue (unless you pull in geometry as well).

Comment: answer accepted because it addresses cursor behavior in original question; in case anyone has a similar issue, I posted working code below as another answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Vince's comments** and **user2856's answer/comments**, the following worked. Elapsed time = 30.17 seconds for 52,000 row, which seems slow.

```
temp1 = r'mypath\mypointfile.shp'
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(temp1, ['OID@', 'group', 'id'])
rows = list(cursor)
dict_ids = {}
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    oid = row[0]
    group_current = row[1]
    id_current = row[2]
    if id_current == 1:
        check = "keep"
    else:
        try:
            row_next = rows[i + 1]
            id_next = row_next[2]
            if vid_next == 1:
                check = "keep"
            else:
                check = "remove"
        except IndexError:
            check = "keep"
        except:
            print 'something else went wrong'
    dict_ids.update([(oid, check)])
del i, row, check
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(temp1, ['OID@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        oid = row[0]
        if oid in dict_ids:
            check = dict_ids.get(oid)
        else:
            print 'error with dictionary'
            sys.exit()
        if check != "keep":
            cursor.deleteRow()

later = datetime.datetime.now()
elapsed = later - now
print elapsed
```

Comment: That is slow, your code takes 2 seconds for me on a local FGDB feature class with 52,000 records. Make sure you're not running it on data on a network drive.

Comment: yes, it is slow. no network, all local.